# quotes around filenames confuse bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script, filenames

I am writing a script that applies a command to loads of files. The way I automate this boils down to

```
#!/bin bash
for in_file in ${PWD}/*/*/*.txt; do
    out_file="${in_file//in/out}"
    CM="/usr/local/bin/command -in \"${in_file}\" -out \"${out_file}\""
    echo ${CM}
    ${CM}
done
```

The typical output I get is

```
/usr/local/bin/command -in "/home/user/infile.txt" -out "/home/user/outfile.txt"
error:
/usr/local/bin/command: unable to find file "/home/user/infile.txt"
...
```

But then I cut & paste the same command, verbatim, including all the quotes etc., on the command prompt, and it runs without a problem!

Because many file names (that I did not make!) have spaces, I need the quotes in the script. But can someone tell me why they do not work in the script and do work on the command prompt? And is there a way to do it properly?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"

Comment: +1 Using functions, that looks like scripting as Brian Fox intended. I know I should, but it feels like overkill for small scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array: that's the best way to preserve a multi-word command with arguments containing whitespace.

```
#!/bin bash
for in_file in ${PWD}/*/*/*.txt; do
    out_file="${in_file//in/out}"
    cmd=( /usr/local/bin/command -in "$in_file" -out "$out_file" )
    echo "${cmd[@]}"
    "${cmd[@]}"
done
```

Comment: that is an excellent (and very clean) way to do it -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"${CM}" will not use blank characters as separators. So bash thinks the whole string is the name of your program.

With ${CM} bash think the " are part of the argument.

You could use << eval "${CM}" >> but you could have side effects with unescaped special chars in file names.

So better is the following :

Does this work ?

```
#!/bin bash
for in_file in "$PWD"/*/*/*.txt; do
    out_file="$in_file/in/out"
    CM="/usr/local/bin/command -in \"$in_file\" -out \"$out_file\""
    echo "${CM}"
    /usr/local/bin/command -in "$in_file" -out "$out_file"
done
```

Instead of echoing your commands, use "set -x" to debug your script :

```
#!/bin bash
set -x
for in_file in "$PWD"/*/*/*.txt; do
    out_file="$in_file/in/out" 
    /usr/local/bin/command -in "$in_file" -out "$out_file"
done
```

or this :

```
#!/bin bash
for in_file in "$PWD"/*/*/*.txt; do
    out_file="$in_file/in/out" 
    set -x
    /usr/local/bin/command -in "$in_file" -out "$out_file"
    set +x
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works -- but the idea was not to have to repeat typing (or having in the script) the same command. I did not know the `set -x` and `set -e` lines, nice! (the `+x` is required!)